# Unable to connect Google firebase with MIT App Inventor

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, app-inventor

I am making this alcohol detector project for my college where I have created an app using MIT app inventor for the purpose of displaying the alcohol level, status of the driver(drunk or sober) and sharing the location.

The location sharing part is working fine. The value of alcohol level and status is also changing in the firebase, according to the input. But, I cannot connect the firebase with app inventor and that's why the app is not displaying the alcohol level and status.

I have copied the URL and firebase token properly, still unable to resolve the problem.

This is the first screen which is supposed to display the parameters:
[image]

This is the firebase which I am trying to connect:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keep this current code.
use one button and on that button click call the get firebase tag method.
and then copy all the code that you have added in the data change method and add that code to got value method also.
this will work.
or watch this one https://youtu.be/ES26E4r_uEU